# How do i Get the difference between the current date and a Date in the database and Display it in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM debtors WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DueDate,'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()";
```

This is the sql query I use to fetch the dates which have passed today's date.

Comment: im using sql dbms

Comment: SQL is a language, specified by ISO/ANSI. Perhaps you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: actually this is for my college project i am doing it in phpmyadmin

Comment: Then FYI : you are currently using MySQL or MariaDB since CURDATE only exist on those AFAIK

Comment: i think im using MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the difference, based on your query. using `datediff`

```
$query= "SELECT *, datediff(curdate(), DueDate) FROM debtors WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DueDate,'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man finally got the answer thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$query=SELECT *,DATEDIFF(mm,YOUR_DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as diffInMonth FROM debator;
```

May be helpful to you.It works in MS SQL 2012 for me.
DATEDIFF(interval,start_date,end_date);

Comment: $query= "SELECT *, datediff(curdate(), DueDate) as dd FROM debtors WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DueDate,'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()";    i tried this and its working thnks to @metal

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this one:

```
$query= "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(DueDate, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS days FROM debtors WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DueDate,'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()";
```

Comment: Thanks for  the answer bt i tried @metal answer and  it working fine